# How to turn off vibration for incoming messages in Google Chat (not Hangouts) - Android 10?

Tags: notifications, google, vibration

I can't find a setting anywhere in that app. I'm aware of the options present: All messages, New threads, @mentions, etc.

I want those notifications. I just don't want the vibration.

Tried going into *Manage your google account*. Couldn't find anything there either.

Tried several google search queries:

```
turn off vibration notification google chat site:reddit.com
turn off vibration notification "google chat" site:reddit.com
turn off vibration notification "google chat" site:reddit.com -intitle:hangouts
turn off vibration notification "google chat" site:superuser.com -intitle:hangouts
turn off vibration notification "google chat" site:stackexchange.com -intitle:hangouts
```

Nothing was useful.

Comment: I noticed, just by accident, that on my phone vibration is turned off when the battery manager is on. So this might be a fallback for other vibrating apps.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to App Info
- Click on Notifications

  [image]
- Click on the Messages (didn't know that it could be clicked; was assuming it'd just toggle)

  [image]
- Expand the Advanced section

  [image]
- Toggle Vibrate

Was desperate; so decided to ask SE.

But, found the answer right before submitting it; so, sharing it.